# XNA not recognizing new class

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

So XNA 4.0 is being a pain in the butt and selectively not recognizing classes.

I have two projects in my solution, **2DRPGLibrary** and **Avalon**. A class in **Avalon**, named *GamePlayScreen*, is trying to reference 2 classes in **2DRGLibrary**: *World* and *WorldBuilder*.

However, *WorldBuilder* gives me the annoying "Type or namespace X could not be found" error. I've included a reference to **2DRPGLibrary** in **Avalon**, and *World* doesn't produce an error. It's only tripping over *WorldBuilder*.

Help?

EDIT: The only thing that seems relevant is that the 2DRPGLibrary has a Client target class when it should be v4.0 instead. There doesn't seem to be a way to fix this, though, because it doesn't have a .csproj file like Avalon...thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the reason could be that the implementation of WorldBuilder is using some classes or libraries that Avalon project doesn't have reference to. And these classes or libraries are not registered on the GAC (Global Assembly Cache).

For example: 2DRGLibrary has reference to library A contained in the A.dll file under that project, WorldBuilding uses some classes of A library for its implementation while World doesn't use any. Then Avalon has reference to 2DRGLibrary and use WorldBuilding but doesn't have a reference to library A.

Just check your referencing on both projects to make sure that the above situation is not present then you should be ok.

Comment: Just double-checked my references. WorldBuilder uses the same references as World, and Avalon and 2DRPGLibrary have the exact same references listed.